# Can't sort string list as number?

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a string list like this

```
"978.8"
"9600.8"
"97.988"
```

After search through all the related question i try the most common way to sort the list as numeric

```
   var newvalues = new List<string>() {"978.8","97.988","9600.8"};
   newvalues.OrderBy(x => double.Parse(x.Value));
```

But it always end up sort the list as default string value

```
"9600.8"
"97.988"
"978.8"
```

I tried other kind of convert but it still didn't work out. Has anybody struggle with this before? How can i fix this?

Comment: How do you assign the result of the `OrderBy`? What is  your current culture?

Comment: Your `OrderBy` clause should work. Without the full code it is impossible to figure out what went wrong.

Comment: You did not show where the problem is! You just gave us input data and result you getting, but didn't show HOW you getting them. I haven't struggled with this at all, because [it works as expected](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fc1B9a).

Comment: @Sefe i just upload the same code, it's that simple

Comment: @PatrickHofman US

Comment: You need to assign the results to a new variable. And what is `x.Value`? it's `double.Parse(x)`.

Comment: OrderBy returns new ordered object

Comment: You need to know that `OrderBy` returns a value; it doesn't alter the original list. Therefore, you need to assign that value to a variable.

Comment: Given that he shows a different ordering at the bottom compared to the top I guess he knows that `OrderBy` returns an ordered collection. The problem here is the sorting, which is done lexicographically, that is depending on the characters, and not on the numerical value. In other words, the list is sorted as *text*, because of the type being `string`. To sort it based on numerical value, you need to get it to be a collection of numbers, instead of a collection of strings.

Comment: The reason why `"978"` comes after `"9600"` is because 9>6, it is done character-by-character, the way text is sorted.

Answer (score 1):

`List<T>.OrderBy()` does not do ordering in place, but returns a new ordered list. So you have to save the result of this method call into your variable.:

```
newvalues = newvalues.OrderBy(x => double.Parse(x)).ToList();
```

Comment: *but returns a new ordered list* Nope. It returns an ordered enumerable.

Comment: right :-) With "list" I was not referring to the type ```List<T>```, but used the common spoken word for a series of data. But my code below made it clear, when I added the ```.ToList()``` call after the ```OrderBy()```

Comment: still not work :(

Comment: the code works for me. What do you get as result?
          var newvalues = new List<string>() { "978.8", "97.988", "9600.8" };
      newvalues = newvalues.OrderBy(x => double.Parse(x, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToList();
      foreach(var x in newvalues) { Console.WriteLine(x); }

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a `List<string>` like this one:

```
List<string> theStringList = new List<string>() { "978.8", "9600.8", "97.988" };
```

If you need the output to still be a `List<string>`, you're on the right track, but as explained in the comments, you need to assign the value returned by `OrderBy` to a variable *because it doesn't actually alter the original list*. you can either assign the value to a new variable of type `List<string>`, like this:

```
var newStringList = theStringList.OrderBy(x => double.Parse(x)).ToList();
```

Or you can assign the value to the same variable, like this:

```
theStringList = theStringList.OrderBy(x => double.Parse(x)).ToList();
```

However, if you want the output to be a `List<double>`, you can do something like this:

```
var newDoubleList = theStringList.Select(x => double.Parse(x)).OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
```